# GeneratedField() ValueError("Cannot force an update in save() with no primary key.")

Tags: django, django-models

In my Employee model, I defined a field called "full_name" declared as a models.GeneratedField like so:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    mid_name = models.CharField('Middle name', max_length=75)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    full_name = models.GeneratedField(
    expression=Concat(
        "last_name", Value(", "), "first_name", Value(" "), "mid_name"
        ),
    output_field=models.CharField(max_length=250),
    db_persist=True,
    )
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                         on_delete=models.SET(get_sentinel_user))
```

However, when I tried to save a record in the admin page, I got ValueError("Cannot force an update in save() with no primary key."). To find out what causes the problem, I tried the following:

- Commented out the user field, and the system worked just fine.
- Re-instated back the user field, but changed to on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True. Runserver and tried adding records in the admin page. Here, I observed that:

1. If I left the user field blank, the system worked just fine.
2. If I set the field with an existing user, this is where the system error occured.

Anyone else encountered this problem? How did you fix this? Or is this some kind of a bug?
django 5.0

Comment: What  is `get_sentinel_user`?

Comment: get_sentinel_user is a function that will return username=deleted

Comment: revised my model without using GeneratedField().. had to resort back to the old fashion way

Comment: This problem was fixed by upgrading to the latest release of Django v5.01.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed with the release of Django v5.0.1